# SSD causes my computer to freeze on bios splash screen

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

I have a 30GB SSD with Windows 7 installed on it (comp specs down below). After doing something a while ago (unfortunately I can't remember what) something happened to my SSD. When the SSD is now connected to the computer on boot, the computer freezes on the bios splash screen.

Things that might be worth mentioning:

- The SSD boots fine when connected to another computer
- My computer works fine when the SSD is not connected
- It also works fine when the SSD is connected after the bios screen [1]
- I have got it working by transferring the files to another hard drive and fixing it from there. [2]
- The SSD is very full, less than a gig of free space from 30. As a result of this I have had to hard shutdown when Windows Update would hang overnight (I read that you need at least 3 gigs of free space to update .NET framework)

[1] - My current workaround is having only the TB HDD with data on it connected, this gets it past the bios to a screen that says "Reboot and Select proper boot device or Insert Boot Media in Selected Boot device and press a key". At this point I used the sata cable connected to the HDD and move it to the SSD, and then use other sata cables to connect the remaining drives.

I have tried:

- Using different sata cables and ports
- Changing sata mode from achi to ide
- Reseting the BIOS (by using the CMOS jumper as described in the mobo manual)
- Using various repair tools from linux (boot-repair, gdisk, testdisk)
- I tried disabling the bios screen to see post but it froze on a blank
  black screen just before post.
- Another thing I tried was coping the content to another drive. I
  tried this using 2 methods, first, dd to clone the entire disk, and second,
  just a simple cp command to copy all the files and directories.

  - When I tried the first method, the second hard drive acted like the first and froze on bios.
  - [2] - The second method however worked better. I cant remember exactly what I did first (might have been testdisk, something similar or even the Windows Repair Disc(had a bit of difficulty getting it recognized)) but I got it to boot to a grub rescue commandline. From there I reinstalled the mbr using lilo and then used the Windows Repair Disc. After that it booted fine (haven't tested it out properly though). While I do realize that I can follow the same process for the SSD (assuming I can remember what I did), I would much rather to find out what is actually causing the problem and fix that.

---

Computer Specs:

> Motherboard: Asus P8P67 Pro
>   Storage:
>   - 30GB SSD - Windows 7
>   - 1TB HDD - Ubuntu* and data
>   - 1TB HDD - More data
>   - 80GB HDD - Arch and an empty 40 gig partition
>
> *While the aim is to eventually setup grub with both OSs, I am confident that I can do that myself. I am asking this question because I am looking for help on fixing my windows drive, not setting up grub.

Comment: Is there a Bios update available for that board? https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8P67_PRO/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: You may have a corrupted boot sector but a correctly working SSD.  Some BIOSses do not handle that very well.

Comment: @Moab I haven't yet tried that as I didn't want to unnecessarily risk bricking my motherboard but I'll give it a shot now.

Comment: @Moab I am trying to update it but its frozen on the dialog box that says "Update successfully! System will be reset!" It has been frozen on this for 10 mins...

Comment: Do a hard restart and pray, I have had this issue before and had no issue doing a hard restart, Update Successful message is a good sign. Nothing else you can do either.

Comment: @Moab Should I use the reset button or the power button?

Comment: either one will work, sorry about your trouble with the update....

Comment: @Moab It is just showing a black screen and the cpu led is red. Also, pretty sure this is my fault, i only just read that it had to be a fat32 usb instead of ntfs hdd. Also, i didnt reset the setting to defaulf.

Comment: power down, pull power cord and remove the cmos battery for 15 minutes, reinsert it and power up. See if bios recovers.

Comment: @Moab Ok, should i move the cmos jumper aswell?

Comment: both do the same thing (remove power) either move the jumper for 15 min or remove the battery.

Comment: @Moab I did both at the same time and it hasnt fixed it. The cpu led is still red...